# Dynamic DAX Number Format

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I want to dynamically change the number format of a DAX measure, based on a dimension value (or indeed, based on the order of magnitude of the measure value).

I understand I can use `SWITCH` and `FORMAT`, as demonstrated by Kaspar De Jonge here: https://www.kasperonbi.com/dynamic-format-using-dax/

Here's an example of the type of measure I'm creating:

```
My Measure:=IF ( 
    HASONEVALUE ( dimMeasureType[Measure Type] ), 
    SWITCH ( VALUES ( dimMeasureType[Measure Type] ),
        "Total Cost", FORMAT ( [Total Cost], "#,##0, k" ),
        "Cost Per Unit", FORMAT ( [Cost Per Unit], "#,##0.00" ),
        "Cost % Sales", FORMAT ( [Cost % Sales], "0.00%" ),
        BLANK()
    ),
    BLANK()
)
```

But this technique returns **text** measures. I need to be able to chart my measures, so I do not want to convert them to text. Is there another technique for dynamically changing a measure number format, without converting to a string?

If it makes a difference, I'm working in SSAS-Tabular on SQL Server 2016 BI.

Comment: Did you try this method already? If so - can you post the format strings you used?

Comment: Yes, I've tried. I can easily format the measures in the way I want - but the problem is that using FORMAT returns text. I want number values, formatted dynamically.

Comment: Can you try some pre-defined numeric formats https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/pre-defined-numeric-formats-for-the-format-function

Comment: Regardless of whether the format is custom or pre-defined, the `FORMAT` function returns text, not numbers.

Comment: Not possible man, vote it up though. I've been looking for a work around to this for quite a while. If you figure something out PLEASE post it here.

Comment: It is possible with calculation groups, do you know it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible in Power BI using dynamic format strings.

Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-dynamic-format-strings

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe this is currently possible, but it a [popular feature request](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/15231165-conditional-formatted-measures-using-switch) that will hopefully be implemented in the future.

I recommend voting and commenting on the idea I linked to in order to add your support.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to create multiple measures and add them all to your chart. Depending on your dimension value only one measure returns values, all other measures return `BLANK()` and are not displayed in your chart. You can give them the same display name by adding whitespace to the end of their names:

```
My Measure:=IF ( 
    SELECTEDVALUE( dimMeasureType[Measure Type] ) = "Total Cost", 
    [Total Cost],
    BLANK()
)
[My Measure ]:=IF ( 
    SELECTEDVALUE( dimMeasureType[Measure Type] ) = "Cost Per Unit", 
    [Cost Per Unit],
    BLANK()
)
[My Measure  ]:=IF ( 
    SELECTEDVALUE( dimMeasureType[Measure Type] ) = "Cost % Sales", 
    [Cost % Sales],
    BLANK()
)
```

This has some drawbacks though:

- The chart legend shows all measures, even if all their values are `BLANK()`.
- The y-Axis of your chart has the same format as the first measure in its 'Values' section.